# Rails: How do I auto-update associated table attributes when parent attributes are updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, associations

I'm trying to update associated table's attributes as soon as the parent attributes are updated. So menus table is the master table and whenever the master is updated, associated attributes in child table (eg. active_status) need to be updated. In order to do this, I added 'after_update' callback in menu model. However, I got was an error below. What did I do wrong here?

Error

> NoMethodError in MenusController#update undefined method `menu_states'
>   for nil:NilClass
>
> Extracted source (around line #54): 52 53 54 55 56 57
>
> def update_menu_states_for_menu
>       @menu.menu_states do |menu_state|
>         self.menu_states.update_attributes(menu_id: menu_state.id, price: menu_state.price, active_status: menu_state.active_status)
>       end    end

menu.rb

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
after_update :update_menu_states_for_menu

  def update_menu_states_for_menu
    menu.menu_states do |menu_state|
      self.menu_states.update_attributes!(menu_id: menu_state.id, price: menu_state.price, active_status: menu_state.active_status)
    end 
  end
```

Models

```
class MenuState < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu
end

class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :menu_states
end
```

Tables

```
local_menus
    t.integer  "restaurant_id",  limit: 4
    t.integer  "menu_id",        limit: 4
    t.boolean  "active_status",    limit: 1
    t.boolean  "instock_status", limit: 1
    t.integer  "price",          limit: 4
    t.integer  "selling_price",  limit:4


menus
    t.integer  "restaurant_id",      limit: 4
    t.string   "name",               limit: 255
    t.integer  "price",              limit: 4
    t.integer  "brand_id",           limit: 4
    t.integer  "category_id",        limit: 4
    t.text     "description",        limit: 65535
    t.boolean  "active_status",      limit: 1
    t.date     "start_date"
    t.date     "end_date"
```

Answer (score 1):

it would be `self.menu_states` instead of `menu.menu_states`

```
def update_menu_states_for_menu
    self.menu_states do |menu_state| # 
      menu_state.update_attributes!(menu_id: menu_state.id, price: menu_state.price, active_status: menu_state.active_status)
    end 
  end
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not save the changes of menus table to menu_states table although the error disappeared. I'm expecting the following SQL statement to be fired right after the menu update action:  "UPDATE `menu_states` SET `price` = xxx, `active_status` = x WHERE `menus`.`id` = xx"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Active Record Autosave Association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html).
Define your `Menu` model like this:

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_states, autosave: true
end
```